# Why is there a SIGSEGV here?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to run this code here at http://ideone.com/YisrPH.

I am getting an SIGSEGV in this function -

```
int minDistance(string A, string B) {
    cout << "HEUI";
    int m = A.length();
    int n = B.length();
    cout << "H";
    int i, j;
    cout << "H";
    // int dist[m+1][n+1];
    // for(i=0;i<=m;i++)
    //     for(j=0;j<=n;j++)
    //         dist[i][j] = 0;
    cout << "H";
    vector<vector<int>> d(m+1, vector<int>(n+1,0));
    cout << "H";
    for(i=0;i<=m;i++) {
        for(j=0;j<=n;j++) {
            if(i==0) d[i][j] = j;
            if(j==0) d[i][j] = i;
            else if(A[i-1]==B[j-1]) d[i][j] = d[i-1][j-1];
            else d[i][j] = 1 + min(d[i-1][j], d[i][j-1], d[i-1][j-1]);
            // cout << dist[i][j] << i << j << endl;
        }
    }
    // cout << dist[m][n];
    return d[m][n];
}
```

As you would notice, I am using vectors to construct a 2D array. If I replace that to use a normal 2D array, it runs, but the result is sometimes correct, and sometimes junk.

Comment: I think `if(j==0)` should be an `else if`, otherwise you might get to `A[i-1]` with `i` being zero.

Comment: Oh god. I spent a good 30 minutes trying to find the mistake. Such a noob mistake I feel stupid now :|

Comment: A debugger would've helped you. I'd say you should learn how to use it.

Comment: I think you probably asked the wrong question. A more useful question for you to ask is "how do I figure out why my code is generating a SIGSEGV". There are a few techniques that would have allowed you to find the problem in few minutes.

Comment: Feel free to elaborate :)

Comment: Was using the IDE of an online judge. Was on a computer with no access to a C++ IDE. I do know how to use a debugger, but there wasn't one to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing out of bounds of array.Consider `i=0` and `j=1`

```
 for(i=0;i<=m;i++) 
 {
    for(j=0;j<=n;j++) 
    {
        if(i==0) 
            d[i][j] = j;
        if(j==0) 
             d[i][j] = i;
        else if(A[i-1]==B[j-1])    //A[i-1]=A[0-1]=A[-1]
             d[i][j] = d[i-1][j-1];
```

You can try this

```
   if(i==0 || j==0) 
            d[i][j] = (i==0?j:i);
   else if(A[i-1]==B[j-1])
     ...
```

Or better as pointed out by @mch in comments

```
    if(i==0 || j==0) 
            d[i][j] = i+j;
   else if(A[i-1]==B[j-1])
      ...
```

Comment: Oh god. I spent a good 30 minutes trying to find the mistake. Such a noob mistake I feel stupid now :|

Comment: In the `if` is `i` or `j` zero, so you can replace `(i==0?j:i)` by `i+j`.

Comment: @mch.Great.Edited.

Comment: For the future: `valgrind --tool=memcheck`.